# Write error: Cannot write compressed block

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, disk-usage

I'm kinda new in Linux.

I cannot boot. My PC stays in the logo of the motherboard after selecting Ubuntu from GRUB menu.
I have been watching some youtube videos to solve this, since my first error was this:

"*unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)*"

I've tried a few things from recovery mode, but it won't let me do anything because I get  an error that says that my device has no space.

Now I can boot my PC from advanced options in the GRUB menu by selecting an older kernel version (5.8.0-53).

I realized that my boot partition if full.

[image: Screenshot]

**The picture says: Free Space 0B (100% used)**

Maybe this is the problem, Im not really sure.

Would appreaciate your help, since I dont want to lose my data.

If someone needs more info I would be happy to share.

Comment: Search this site for "full boot" and see the many fixes.

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Thank you guys, will try that.

Comment: My ubuntu version: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS